# How can I keep the text resolution and sharp but resize the rectangle?

Tags: animation

This is in the rendering mode I want to cut from both top and bottom and maybe some from the sides the black rectangle background :

[image: Rendering]

This is how it looks like in the layout :

[image: Layout]

When I mean to cut from the top bottom and sides I mean something like that. I did it in pain just to show what I mean but I want it in the blender so the animation when doing later CTRL + F12 to be in that rectangle size and not like in the first screenshot :

[image: How I want it to be]

When I'm doing CTRL + F12 to render the animation it's creating on the hard disk 100 frames that's 100 png images this is the output properties settings :

[image: Output properties settings]

And this is example of image on the hard disk how it is now before making the cutting :

[image: Png image on the hard disk and I want it to be like in the third screenshot]

Tried changing resolution :

[image: Layout after changed resolution/s]

But this is when I changed the mode to Rendering it looks like as before like there are no changes at all :

[image: In rendering it looks like it didn't change anything]

And this is one of the images on the hard disk after did CTRL + F12 after changed the resolution on Y to 260 :

[image: After changed resolution it changed also the text resolution look at the third screenshot comparing to this one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change that in the "Context", which is the printer-like symbol:

[image: Context]

It has Resolution X and Y properties that will affect the cameras:

[image: Camera rectangle]

Comment: I tried it now clicked on the top right on the Camera then in the printer where the resolution is I changed the Y to 260 but when I click on Rendering it looks like before like it didn't change only on Layout it's changed.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi: ok, that's interesting.

Comment: I updated my question with two screenshots more after changed the resolution/s it should be like that in the Rendering ? It seems like I see the changes only in the layout.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi: did you re-render (Ctrl+F12) after changing the resolution? If you just go to the "Rendering" tab, it will display whatever there was before.

Comment: I did CTRL + F12 now and it did create the images with the rectangle cut like I wanted the problem is that it's also changed the text resolution the text is not that smooth and sharp like in the third screenshot in my question. I added now the screenshot example of how it looks like on the hard disk now.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi: sorry, I can't follow. Too many pictures :-) I think you're comparing two images which have a different point in the timeline. When I look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvLzR.png I can't really see a quality difference. Also, there is no reason where a quality difference should come from